# Consulta con tablas relacionas en SQL y C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tengo este formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este formulario alimenta dos tablas en la base de datos **proyectos** y **estudiantes**, todo bien hasta ese punto, ya que se guardan registros, tanto nuevos proyectos, como estudiantes por separado. Lo que no tengo muy claro es en asignar estudiantes a un proyecto y guardarlo o relacionar los datos y cuando se haga una consulta, por ejemplo de proyectos, arroje qué estudiantes están asignados a él mismo, igual de viceversa, al consultar un estudiante arroje a qué proyecto está asociado.

Tengo conocimiento sobre las *Primary Key* y las *Foreign Keys*, solo necesito una ayuda/guia en crear la relación arriba indicada.

Este es el codigo que utilizo en mi consulta actual (clase estudiantes), como lo modifico para hacer uso del "INNER JOIN" y que la consulta me arroje datos de la dos tablas?

```
public static List<Estudiantes> BuscarEstudiante(String pnombre, String papellido)
    {
        List<Estudiantes> lista = new List<Estudiantes>();
        using (SqlCeConnection conexion = BDc.ObtnerCOnexion())
        {
            SqlCeCommand comando = new SqlCeCommand(string.Format("SELECT idEstudiantes, cedula, nombre, apellido, carrera, condicion, codProyecto FROM estudiantes WHERE nombre LIKE '%{0}%' and apellido LIKE '%{1}%'", pnombre, papellido), conexion);

            SqlCeDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Estudiantes pestudiante = new Estudiantes();
                pestudiante.idEstudiantes = reader.GetInt32(0);
                pestudiante.cedula = reader.GetString(1);
                pestudiante.nombre = reader.GetString(2);
                pestudiante.apellido = reader.GetString(3);
                pestudiante.carrera = reader.GetString(4);
                pestudiante.condicion = reader.GetString(5);
                pestudiante.codProyecto = reader.GetInt32(6);

                lista.Add(pestudiante);
            }
            conexion.Close();
            return lista;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No tengo la reputación para añadir un comentario, pero no te podemos ayudar si no colocas la estructura de las tablas, las imágenes no las pongas

Comment: Por ejemplo para buscar un estudiante esta asignado a un proyecto, vas a crear en C# una clase de proyectos, donde vas a tener el ID del proyecto y el ID del estudiante, cuando quieras obtener datos del estudiante haces la consulta en SQL enviando el ID del estudiante, si queres traer datos del estudiante y del proyecto tenes que hacer un innerjoin

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo queres saber como hacer la relación de estudiante proyecto.

podes unir las dos tablas por medio de una tea.

ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por medio de un alumno podes buscar los proyectos que tienen asignado.
y por medio de un proyecto podes obtener los alumnos asignados.

Actualización.

yo crearía la tabla intermedia de arriba Proyecto_Estudiante.

la consulta en esa tabla seria.

select e.nombre,e.apellido from Proyecto_Estudiante as pe
inner join proyecto as p on p.id=pe.proyecto_id
inner join estudiante as e on e.id=pe.estudiante_id
where e.nombre like '%nombre%'

y si queres usar solo esas 2 tablas, en una de ellas tiene que estar referenciar a la otra y meterle el join.
ejemplo.

SELECT idEstudiantes, cedula, nombre, apellido, carrera, condicion, codProyecto FROM estudiantes as e
inner join Proyecto as p on p.id=e.idproyecto
WHERE nombre LIKE '%{0}%' and apellido LIKE '%{1}%'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.NombreProyecto,t2.NombreEstudiante 
FROM tablaProyecto t1, tablaAlumno t2 
WHERE t1.Id = t2.Id 
ORDER BY  t1.NombreProyecto asc
```

Con esta consulta llenas un datatable y este se lo asignas al datasource del datagridview

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]